# E254: cannot allocate color

Tags: vim, colors

I have been using a local syntax file in my local path `/home/user/.vim/syntax/log.vim` for a while.
In my new workplace when i tried using the same syntax file,it doesn't show the intended colors and instead it gives an error

> **E254:cannot allocate color darkorange**
>
> **E254: Cannot allocate color NONE**

I tried checking colortest code from web it works fine.
[image: when tested in vim]

hi comment guifg=darkorange guibg=NONE  gui=bold

The same color works when i use it in `.vimrc` file.

I am not supposed to change the `/usr/share/vim/vim*/*` path ,if there is any workaround so that i can change in my local path or local vimrc file would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try something like: "setenv VIMRUNTIME /usr/share/vim/current" where /usr/share/vim/current is a link to the subdirectory created by the currently installed vim version, e.g. /usr/share/vim/vim80 for vim version 8.0, and so on -- ?